# Extract the parent node name from Tree who has childrens

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to iterate the tree and need to get the id of all the nodes which has the children in string array. while looping it is just returning me the record but doesn't extract the name of the node.

e.g const result = ['root', 'USER', 'ROLE', 'DASHBOARD', 'BRAND', 'COMPANY'];

```
{
  "id": "root",
  "name": "Roles and Permissions",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "USER",
      "name": "USER",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "VIEW"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "CREATE"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "EDIT"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ROLE",
      "name": "ROLE",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "name": "VIEW"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "name": "CREATE"
        },
        {
          "id": "10",
          "name": "EDIT"
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "name": "DELETE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "DASHBOARD",
      "name": "DASHBOARD",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "BRAND",
          "name": "BRAND",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "52",
              "name": "VIEW"
            },
            {
              "id": "53",
              "name": "CREATE"
            },
            {
              "id": "54",
              "name": "EDIT"
            },
            {
              "id": "55",
              "name": "DELETE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "COMPANY",
          "name": "COMPANY",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "56",
              "name": "VIEW"
            },
            {
              "id": "57",
              "name": "CREATE"
            },
            {
              "id": "58",
              "name": "EDIT"
            },
            {
              "id": "59",
              "name": "DELETE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried various looping method to get the list, e.g. but not returning the exact name of the node.

```
function getParent(nodes) {
    if(Array.isArray(nodes.children)) {
      return nodes.children.map((node) => getParent(node));
    }
    return nodes.name;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the resp in an array and return that array.

```js
const q = {
  "id": "root",
  "name": "Roles and Permissions",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "USER",
      "name": "USER",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "VIEW"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "CREATE"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "EDIT"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ROLE",
      "name": "ROLE",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "name": "VIEW"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "name": "CREATE"
        },
        {
          "id": "10",
          "name": "EDIT"
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "name": "DELETE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "DASHBOARD",
      "name": "DASHBOARD",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "BRAND",
          "name": "BRAND",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "52",
              "name": "VIEW"
            },
            {
              "id": "53",
              "name": "CREATE"
            },
            {
              "id": "54",
              "name": "EDIT"
            },
            {
              "id": "55",
              "name": "DELETE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "COMPANY",
          "name": "COMPANY",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "56",
              "name": "VIEW"
            },
            {
              "id": "57",
              "name": "CREATE"
            },
            {
              "id": "58",
              "name": "EDIT"
            },
            {
              "id": "59",
              "name": "DELETE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


let result = []
function r(nodes){
  if(Array.isArray(nodes.children)){
    result.push(nodes.name);
    nodes.children.map((c) => r(c))
    return result;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(r(q))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the id rather than the name.

Comment: Actually I used name here as in the question it says to extract name, and also in the code snippet it uses name, hence I also used name here, but it can be changed to id, if needed.

Comment: I think the title is wrong. The question says ID and the required output matches that expectation.

Comment: I think both id and name are exact same.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a recursive function. Here `ids` is an array. You can initialize it before calling the function. Call this function in your getting IDs method.

```
const getIdFromNodesWithChild = (node) => {
  if (node.children != undefined){
    ids.push(node.id)
    const children_list = node.children
    children_list.forEach( new_child => getIdFromNodesWithChild(new_child))
}}
```

caller function

```
const returnIds = (tree) => {
  ids = []
  getIdFromNodesWithChild(tree)
  return (ids) 
}
```

result :  `['root', 'USER', 'ROLE', 'DASHBOARD', 'BRAND', 'COMPANY']`